# There can only be one, RIP Sir Sean Connery

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Sean Connery: James Bond actor dies aged 90](https://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-54761824).

Best known for his role as James Bond, which is not considered Sci-Fi or Fantasy, however he did star in many SFF films such as *Zardoz*, *Highlander*, *Indiana Jones*, *First Knight*, and his last appearance on screen in *The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen*.

> He was knighted by the Queen at Holyrood Palace in 2000. In August, he celebrated his 90th birthday.

He was probably one the most recognizable actors of the 20th century and will be missed by all who loved him and his work.

I guess Goldfinger finally got his wish...

Comment: Zardoz was not his finest hour, costume-wise

Comment: Damn. :-(  As if I needed another reason to hate 2020. RIP.

Comment: I mostly know Sean Connery from DMM's Irregular Webcomic "https://irregularwebcomic.net/".  He played both Prof. Jones in the Cliffhangers theme and James Stud in the Espionage theme.  All together he appeared in hundreds of strips.

Answer (score 18):

Sean Connery played both of England's most legendary characters: King Arthur in First Knight, and Robin Hood in Robin and Marian (little known but well worth watching). I wonder if he was the only film actor to play both of these roles.

[image: Robin & Marian]

Comment: Mel Blanc played King Arthur in *[Bugs Bunny in King Arthur's Court](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UuJHz6E6Uw)* and Robin Hood in *[Robin Hood Daffy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hood_Daffy)*.

Comment: I've turned this into [a question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/111469/27759), on M&TV since neither King Arthur nor Robin Hood is necessarily on-topic for SFF.

Comment: Robin and Marian is one of my all time faves.  Very bittersweet film, but well worth watching.   Robert Shaw made for a fine Sheriff of Nottingham, too.

Answer (score 8):

I really enjoyed Connery in the 1981 film Outland.  It's basically High Noon in space, but it's just a great popcorn film with an excellent supporting cast and an Alien-ish look.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Connery had his misses as well. In addition to the [horrifying bad Highlander 2](https://thesffblog.com/2016/02/jacks-bad-movies-highlander-ii-the-quickening/), there was [Zardoz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zardoz), a quintessentially cheesy 70's scifi B-movie that had Connery dressed in... well...

[image: Sean Connery in Zardoz]

It can't go on SFF that we talk about him and skip *that*. Still, James Bond, Capt. Ramius, Indiana Jones' dad and [Malone in *The Untouchables*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPZ6eaL3S2E). One of the most accomplished actors of the 20th century.

Comment: Oh, that outfit. Yikes

Comment: Highlander 2 was an excellent film.

Comment: For Connery, maybe. He gets to laugh as he disappears, almost like he's saying "I'm out, suckers. Thanks for the money."

Comment: odd costumes aside, Zardoz is full of interesting ideas that have been rarely explored.  and Highlander 2 is cheesey as hell, but still entertaining, and I think I prefer Connery's performance in this more than in the first Highlander film - especially his jesting at Hamlet.

Answer (score 5):

Also he had a great role in *The Hunt for Red October*, such a shame that he was driven off acting after getting into arguments with Stephen Norrington on the set of *LXG*.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can read further about the arguments between Sean and Stephen?

Comment: I remember reading it in many magazines at the time but I found this pre-release article https://www.scotsman.com/news/connery-odds-film-director-2466055